# child's child in relativelayout wrong size in android 4.3/4.4

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout in RelativeLayout. And it has a child View. I want to the child has the same height with the LinearLayout, so I do this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="13dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_first"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/top_placeholder_layout"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/child_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/node">
    <View
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/divider_normal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It's ok in android 6.0/5.0.
[image]

but when I use android 4.3/4.4(nexus 5 android4.4.4, zte S291 android4.3, and the 4.3 emulator),the inside view's height always 0. 
Why? Help

Comment: You have a circular dependency. The `LinearLayout ` is asking the `View` and vice versa for height. You have to make it fixed for one.

Comment: @Shaishav I thought that LinearLayout height is depends on the view with id child_content, and my inside divider view height depends on its parent LinearLayout.

Comment: I believe there's still a circular dependency. Can you share your entire layout file?

Comment: @Shaishav I put it on.

Comment: Everything references `@dimens` in your code man :|

Comment: @Shaishav sorry, I replace all of them to dip.

Comment: It appears okay on my end. Like you mentioned, `layout_below` is controlling the height

Comment: @Shaishav It's ok in IDE preview. But it's not ok on nexus 5 or ZTE S291 or emulator

Answer (score 0):

finally , I replace LinearLayout with a android.view.View, and use a 9patch image in view's background to show my vertical line.